# jmeter- missing to save output - save responses to a file

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am doing a performance test for an API and trying to hit it 120 times within a minute. Every time I hit, the output files written to the folder is less than 120. I never get the correct number of output files. Sometimes, I get 119, 115, 117.

Out of 120 hits, 50% is passed and 50% is failure scenarios. When checked the output folder, files are missed to write from both passed and failed scenarios.

Could someone help me to understand what could be the reason?

Jmeter Version 3.1

Comment: You need to add more details what is the expected response of API and what is the failure message you are receiving. Your question is just generic doesn't create interest to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest temporarily enabling storing request and response details. You can do it by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file (the file is located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

1. Once done - restart JMeter to pick the property up
2. Run your test
3. When it's finished open .jtl results file with [View Results Tree listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and inspect request and especially response details to detect any issues
4. If you won't find any clues add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   log_level.jmeter.reporters.ResultSaver=DEBUG
   ```

   and look for the message starting with

   > Error saving sample ....

Don't forget to revert back the configuration changes once you do the troubleshooting.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)